# Is there a way to manually purge API responses from AWS CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

Let's say I'm caching responses via the Cache-Control header and I don't want to wait for max-age to hit, because I'm churning my API and want to manually clear it. Reading the documentation I could only see a topic about invalidating files, but nothing about API response cache. Perhaps what I'm trying to do is impossible, other than reset the entire CloudFront?

Would this command clear API responses:

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id=YOUR_DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths "/*"
```

Comment: Yes, this cmd will purge all CF cache.

Comment: What if I don't want to invalidate all API responses, but just a particular microservice's? F.e. let's say I have a service with base path:

/serviceA

and all my API responses are under that.

Can I write my invalidation(for up to thousands of responses) for just that path? I read that you can only write a single invalidation of up to 3000 items at a time?